# How to store events for an online game in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

As part of an online text based game, I will be simulating game events for a cricket game (or you can consider baseball). There will be an event generated for each delivery bowled (or pitch). Events will be of the type 4 runs, 2 runs, wickets, etc. For each event, there will be multiple players involved, bowler, fielder and batsman.

The design that I have in mind is such:

```
**Table 1 - MatchEvent** 
    EventID 
    EventType 
    BowlerID 
    BatsmenID 
    FielderID


**Table 2 - Commentary**
    CommentaryID
    GameID
    Innings
    DeliveryNum
    EventID
```

The concern that I have is that, there will be at least 600 rows per match simulated.

Is there a better way to design the table, considering that I need to replay the results to the users per delivery.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how cricket is played, so sorry for the dumb question, but how do you arrive at 600 rows/events per match? Isn't each run + wicket 1 event?

Comment: A game consists of 50 overs per innings. Each over consists of 6 deliveries that a bowler bowls. So 300 deliveries per innings. 2 innings make a game.

Comment: For each delivery, we will simulate an event to occur. These events need to be stored with the players who are involved in that event. Hence 600 rows or events per match.

Comment: You can simplify your events by gathering, e.g. all 50 overs and only display the results of that inning, or collect all 6 deliveries and only make interactions for innings if no user action is required. If that's not possible. You can have tables for deliveries, innings, games, etc. and then have the inning delete its deliveries-events after it's completed and so on. You will have to profile whether keeping the events works better than having lots of writes into the database (inserting/deleting events). mysql can perform well even with millions of records if you setup the tables correctly.

Comment: Why do you have to store each delivery with a user and more precisely does it have to be persisted indefinitely? As far as I can tell a delivery-event is only useful during an inning or game. If this is only data shown to the user you can store a summary and display it differently. I doubt that you will have 600 interactions per player/game? How many games does a season(?) have? If you assign indizes well, having 600x100 (or even 1000) game events seems like it can be handled easily by mysql. After the season you move the info somewhere else and clear events.

Comment: The event has to be stored to be replayed to the user in a format similar to [http://www.espncricinfo.com/new-zealand-v-bangladesh-2016-17/engine/match/1019973.html?innings=1;view=commentary]. You will need to scroll below to see the commentary per delivery. There will be more than 600 interactions, as even if no runs are scored, we will need to display it to the user. We can look at clearing events after 1 season.